# MySQLdb in Python: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'"

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have installed MySQLdb for Python and I am able to import MySQLdb. Now I try to connect to the MySQL Community Server on my local machine, using this code:

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="br_admin",
    passwd="blabla",
    db="br_brain"
)
```

This code fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 5, in <module>
  db="brainse_brain"
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you connect to the server on localhost outside of python?

Comment: NO.The problem is.. Im not able to figure out the host name from my cpanel. In my phpmyadmin in variables i have the hostname as "XXXXXXX"...   but when I try its effectless.....

Answer (score 41):

Make sure to provide the proper host and port:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'yourdbname',                      
    'USER': 'root',                      
    'PASSWORD': 'your password',         
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                 
    'PORT': '3306',                      
},
```

This is my settings.py file config for my django app.

Same for you please take host "127.0.0.1" and port "3306".

This might solve your problem.
And for python idle I've tested like...

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> Con = MySQLdb.Connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, user="yoruname", passwd="yourpwd", db="test")
>>> Cursor = Con.cursor()
>>> sql = "SELECT * FROM test.testing"
>>> Cursor.execute(sql)
2L
```

Comment: Actually the problem in my case was that I was using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1". Anyway, the simple test you provided was a very welcome help.

Comment: In my case, I accidently supplied the username as the password. Check that all your credentials are correct (instead of assuming they are).

Comment: Documentation for mysqldb says it defaults to 3306 however at least as of 1.2.3rc1 under python 2.6 I can't connect remotely unless explicitly setting port to 3306.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same trouble too, I'm working on a Windows of 64 bits, and the solution just was changing  the host variable value. I had set "localhost" when the correct value have to be "127.0.0.1". However, when I'm working on Windows of 32 bits. I can set "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" in the host variable value and no matter, my django's project runs perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

This will work fine :

```
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="db_username",passwd="db_password",db="db_name")
```

or

```
   db=  MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","db_username","db_password","db_name")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows you should specify the IP to "127.0.0.1", using "localhost" will give you that error 2003. On Ubuntu I had no problem.

Comment: couldn't get when i give 127.0.01. But got by giving host as 127.0.0.1

Comment: Of course, that's a typo. IP address consists of 4 (1-byte) integers.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 32, if you set host as `127.0.01` it gives the down error:

```
OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.01' (0)")
```

But if you set host as `127.0.0.1` then you get no error.

Comment: That's because 127.0.01 isn't a valid IP address.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to MySQL workbench
2.On the task bar above, click on server->and then click on Startup/Shutdown
3.On the screen, click on Start the server and you will get logs of server starting and running

Answer (score 0):

```
 - DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
           'NAME': 'dataflair',
           'USER':'root',
           'PASSWORD':'',
           'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
           'PORT':'3306',
           'OPTIONS':{
       'init_command':"SET sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.