# "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)" error in python

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-python

Just today I have decided that I wanted to learn python because I personally like the syntax and its feel. I am a pretty young developer and I really wanted to learn a new programming language since I am only fluent in `JavaScript` (especially javascript) and `PHP` so I decided on `Python`. Python seems quite like javascript execpt for the fact that they don't use curly braces to define a new block. And of course its far more powerful.

I've learned that you can connect to `MySQL` databases using `MySQLdb` .

But I am having an issue, when I use the following code.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="methodjs_postes", passwd="********", db="methodjs_postes");
```

I get this large error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="methodjs_postes", passwd="********", db="methodjs_postes");
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

The main part that I was really focusing on though was the `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)` part. (But it would be nice if you explain the other parts too)

I don't see why i'm getting this issue. 
I use `localhost` in my `PHP` and it works just fine. And I did `import` the `MySQLdb` which I don't think is the error because then it wouldn't even attempt to connect.

I am using `python 2.7`, I would be using 3.3 (have it downloaded) but `MySQLdb` only supports up to 2.7.

When using `select User,Host,Password from mysql.user where User like '%methodjs_postes%';` I get the following error:

`SELECT command denied to user 'methodjs'@'localhost' for table 'user'`

Comment: Yes, TCP. Do you know why the connection gets refused?

Comment: It looks like MySQL isn't listening on the port you think it listens on. Can you "force" it to the same value that you use with PHP?

Comment: @fge I am using the same values as when I connect with PHP. If you want I can post an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQLdb in Python: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121819/mysqldb-in-python-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost)

Comment: @Shawn31313 indeed, localhost is specific to each machine, try using the other machine's IP address instead. It may still fail if 1. MySQL is not listening on the interface or 2. it does, but there are no entries in the privilege tables allowing the user to connect from that IP

Comment: Okay, hmm, I still can't seem to get it to connect. I did try the answer on the "possible duplicate". Question, can I write python on just any editor and add .py like you can just write PHP and add .php ?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `select User,Host,Password from mysql.user where User like '%methodjs_postes%';` into your question?

Comment: How do you want the output? What function do you want me to put that in? (I know its sql)

Comment: Use any mysql client and execute that query. So it will give you the details of that user's login permissions. That way, we can figure it out one possibile reason for this error.

Comment: Okay its in my question now.

Comment: Login as `root` or `admin` user to execute that query.. Your user `methodjs` don't have that much permission to query `mysql` table in your `MySQL` server.

Comment: No. `root` / `admin` pass.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22618/discussion-between-shawn31313-and-suku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22618/discussion-between-shawn31313-and-suku

As per out chat, the conclusion is :- "Your mysql host is a remote machine and which is not allowing remote mysql connections"

Answer (score 3):

Just replace localhost with 127.0.0.1

Comment: This worked for me. The reason was that my OS DNS couldn't resolve `localhost`.