I am having a problem in MySQL connection in Python which I never had before

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 733, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\Python codes\cars.py", line 3, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "S:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 294, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "S:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "S:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1217, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "S:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 575, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "S:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 735, in open_connection
    raise InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)


This is what appears when I try to connect MySQL db to Python
What could be the cause of this error, and how to fix it?
Given below is the code I am trying to run
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "xxxxx",
        database='xxxxx'
)
mydb.close()

This is a code I wrote for testing the MySQL connection before using it for a larger project. And the given problem arose.
The password and database name are not the same as given here.

Try host = "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25887888/26993270)

"actively refused it" means that either there's no mysql daemon running on the machine or there's a firewall blocking the connection. Since firewalls don't usually affect localhost, it probably means the server crashed.

Or mysql is running just on a different port or it is configured not to listen to TCP connections coming from the same host (unlikely)
